# Ruby: how to get at meridian in Time objects?

Tags: ruby, time

If I've got a time object:

```
t = Time.now
```

and I want to know if that time is AM or PM, right now the only way I can figure to do this is:

```
t.strftime("%p") == "PM"
```

Now, that `%p` is getting interpolated from something, right? Is there another way to get to it?

I ask because I'm doing some time formatting where I want to display a time range like:

```
"9:00 AM - 5:00 PM"
"4:00 - 5:30 PM"
"10:15 - 11:45 AM"
```

Right now I have to do this checking the string value of `strftime`, but I'd prefer to write something like:

```
if start_time.am? && end_time.pm? || start_time.pm? && end_time.am?
```

...instead of the much more verbose `strftime` string comparisons I'm doing now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html, I do not believe there is any other way. You could monkey-patch Time to save you some tedious strftime, however:

```
class Time
  def meridian
    self.strftime('%p')
  end

  def am?
    self.meridian == 'AM'
  end

  def pm?
    self.meridian == 'PM'
  end
end
```

Comment: Cool. I figured something like this might be the only way, thanks for the example.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything as nice as `time.am?` but you can use `time.hour < 12` instead.

Comment: great suggestion, I decided to combine your checking method with bioneuralnet's monkey patch. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Time
  def am?
    self.hour.in? (0..12)
  end

  def pm?
    self.hour.in? (13..24)
  end
end
```

Comment: In Ruby 1.9.2 : in 'am?': undefined method 'in?' for 2:Fixnum (NoMethodError). But this works : 

    `def am?
        (0..12).include?(hour)
      end`

Comment: Yeah. `in?` is Rails shortcut method. In pure Ruby you should use `include?`